# How to determine the type of json object in go

Tags: json, go

In [gobyexample.com/json](https://gobyexample.com/json), a few examples show how to decode `json` string into typed objects or dictionary objects, which are declared as `map[string]interface{}`. But it assumes the result is always a dictionary.

So my question is how to determine the type of `json` object and what is the best practice to handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the definition of json.Unmarshal:

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

So at least you can obtain the underlying type by using reflect.

```
var v interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(JSON_STR), &v)
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(v), reflect.ValueOf(v))
```

And `switch` definitely is a better practice. I suppose below snippet

```
switch result := v.(type) {
case map[string]interface{}:
    fmt.Println("dict:", result)
case []interface{}:
    fmt.Println("list:", result)
default:
    fmt.Println("value:", result)
}
```

can basically meet your requirement.